# How to mock a field in object in kotlin?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, singleton, mockk

I have a class

```
object Sender {
    private val emailSender: EmailSender = EmailSender()

    fun sendMessage(text: String) {
        val message = Message(text)
        message.createHeader()
        emailSender.send(message)
    }
}
```

I need to write a test for `sendMessage`. I use JUnit5 and MockK libraries. How can I mock `emailSender`? Is it possible?

Comment: Presumably you'd need to do dependency injection so you can pass in a custom `EmailSender` to the constructor -- and make `sender` a `class`, not an `object`, while you're at it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quite difficult setup since you initialize the `emailSender` before anything can be mocked, and the `emailSender` is not accessible from outside.

If you want to keep `Sender` as an `object` and `emailSender` as a private property, it would help to initialize the `emailSender` not on startup, but lazily on the first call:

```kotlin
object Sender {
    private val emailSender: EmailSender by lazy { EmailSender() }
    ...
}
```

Then you can use [Mockk's `mockConstructor`](https://mockk.io/#constructor-mocks) to mock the constructor of `EmailSender` which does also takes effect for the lazily initialized property `emailSender`:

```kotlin
@Test
fun test() {
    mockkConstructor(EmailSender::class) {
        every { anyConstructed<EmailSender>().send(any()) } just runs

        Sender.sendMessage("x")

        verify { anyConstructed<EmailSender>().send(any()) }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there method using mockito not mockk?